# Uso do Google AdMob

Tags: java, android, firebase, admob

estou usando o google admob para colocar anúncios no meu aplicativo, porém tenho algumas dúvidas

1. Posso usar o mesmo bloco de anúncio (id) para várias activity (cada uma com um bloco)?
2. Como fazer para que o anúncio seja a primeira coisa a carregar? a ideia é que o tempo que o usuário leva para fechar o anúncio é o tempo de baixar o banco do firebase

Meu código (resumido):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-5718158120252618~4586568420");

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        carregarAnuncio();

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                carregarAnuncio();
            }
        });

        banco.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                onibus.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    BusAdmin b = data.getValue(BusAdmin.class);
                    b.setKey(data.getKey());

                    onibus.add(b);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void carregarAnuncio() {
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

Por enquanto o anúncio só é carregado depois do banco (firebase) quero justamente o contrário

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1º pergunta: Não, pelo menos eu não recomendo é bom fazer blocos de anúncios separados para cada activity, em aplicações que você trabalha com fragmentos você pode colocar o anúncio por exemplo junto com o conteiner que carrega o fragmento, mas no caso do interstitial é melhor fazer blocos separados.

2º pergunta: 
Normalmente o anúncio demora um pouco pra ser carregado mesmo, isso pode ocorrer a vários fatores seja por ser um anúncio de vídeo ou a internet do usuário, a solução que eu irei te passar pode não ser a das melhores mas resolve seu problema, fiz a parte do showInterstitial() ele abre o interstitial e retorna true, retornando ele carrega o código para baixar o banco do firebase.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private boolean boleanloaded;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boleanloaded = false;

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-5718158120252618~4586568420");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    carregarAnuncio();

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            carregarAnuncio();
        }
    });

    while (!boleanloaded) {
        boleanloaded = showInterstitial();
        if (boleanloaded)
        banco.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                onibus.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    BusAdmin b = data.getValue(BusAdmin.class);
                    b.setKey(data.getKey());

                    onibus.add(b);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });}
    }


}

private void carregarAnuncio() {
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

private boolean showInterstitial() {

    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Não entendo de AdMob**, mas para saber se a conexão ao `Firebase Database` está estabelecida existe um jeito bem fácil. Está bem explicado na guia de desenvolvimento do Google no tópico **Como detectar o estado da conexão** deste [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). Usando o código

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if (connected) {
      System.out.println("connected");
    } else {
      System.out.println("not connected");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

Colocando um `while(!connected){...}` acredito que resolva seu problema.
Ps: lembre-se de utilizar a referência do banco de dados na raiz do seu banco de dados como no exemplo, entrando em um `child` não vai funcionar.